# How to set alias `git tag` for `git tag -s`?

Tags: git, bash

How to set alias `git tag` for `git tag -s`?

```
[alias]
  tag = tag -s
```

Now I can't override this in `.gitconfig`. It's not works as I seen. I think it because `tag` predefined argument of `git`. Can be this done using aliases or functions in Bash?

git version 2.13.1

Comment: Why can't you do this in your `gitconfig`?

Comment: @kabanus It's not works as I seen. I think it because `tag` predefined argument of `git`

Comment: Why not just use a different alias, like "tags" or "ts"? Git doesn't allow overwriting built-ins with aliases.